# Зачем в jvm нужны строковые константы?

Tags: java, компиляция, jvm, виртуальная-машина

Пишу небольшую jvm (не очень строго соблюдая спецификацию) и компилятор под это дело. Столкнулся с таким вот вопросом. По спецификации в пуле констант class файла, имеет место быть константа типа Utf8, служащая как я понял для представления строк. Мне не совсем понятно, для чего она нужна, так как у меня имеется следующая цепочка рассуждений.

В jvm нет строк, их можно представить только как int[]. Для того что бы конечный пользователь не возился с массивами, был сделан класс String, который на вход принимает как раз этот int[] (на уровне java это char[]). А выражение вида:

```
String str = "abc";
```

Разворачивается компилятором таким образом:

```
char[3] t;
t[0] = 'a';
t[1] = 'b';
t[2] = 'c';
String str = new String(t);
```

Те строка так же оказывается пуле констант, но уже как константы типа int (так как char c utf символом разворачивается в short, а все short на уровне вм это int, а любой int > 127 попадает в пул констант (до 127 заносится в стек напрямую через инструкцию bipush)).

Вопрос - зачем нужны константы utf8 (вероятно я неправильно понимаю механику работы строк?)?

P. S. При этом если использовать занесение строк в пул констант как я написал, то получается просто сумасшедшая экономя места, так как для строки например из 1000 кириллических символов, придется выделить 2кб памяти в пуле констант, а для хранения их как int, всего 2 * 4 * кол-во одинаковых символов в строке. Т. е. если например используются только буквы русского алфавита, вся строка займет в пуле всего 66 байт.

Comment: `Разворачивается компилятором таким образом` — точно? Строки, содержимое которых известно на этапе компиляции, как раз и попадают в пул, чтобы не копировать их посимвольно, а просто сослаться, благо объекты типа `String` неизменяемые (immutable).

Answer (score 4):

Ну я как обычно задал вопрос а потом сам разобрался. Строковые константы utf8 необходимы для хранения различной мета-информации, необходимой jvm для функционирования. В пример можно привести работу инструкции new, которая в качестве аргумента, получает адрес в пуле констант, на котором хранится строковая константа с сигнатурой класса. Например для :

new String();

компилятор сгенерирует инструкцию new, аргумент которой будет ссылаться на ячейку пула констант типа utf8 с содержимым - java/lang/String.

Answer (score 1):

В скомпилированном class-файле нет понятия строковой константы. Возможно, вы имели в виду *пул констант*.

Согласно [спецификации Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4):

> 4.4. Пул констант
>
> Инструкции в виртуальной машине Java не полагаются на строение классов, интерфейсов, экземпляров классов и массивов. Вместо этого они указывают на записи в таблице *constant_pool*.
>
> ---
>
> *4.4. The Constant Pool*
>
> *Java Virtual Machine instructions do not rely on the run-time layout of classes, interfaces, class instances, or arrays. Instead, instructions refer to symbolic information in the constant_pool table.*

То есть он хранит не только строки и метаинформацию, а вообще всё, что должно быть размещено в пямяти (а не прямо по месту вызова).

Comment: Он имел ввиду, почему константы в пуле для строк имеют специальный тип utf8, а не представлены просто массивом символов.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, в спецификации видно, что `CONSTANT_Utf8_info` содержит в себе массив, а `CONSTANT_String_info` всего лишь указывает на этот `*_Utf8_*`. То есть `*_String_*` (подобно `*_Integer_*`, `*_Float_*` и прочим) олицетворяет переменную, а `*_Utf8_*` — строковый литерал, на который вполне могут ссылаться и несколько переменных (если у JVM не выключена соответствующая оптимизация).

Comment: Ага, автор про это уже написал ответ ещё 12 сентября.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, `компилятор сгенерирует инструкцию new, аргумент которой будет ссылаться на ячейку пула констант типа utf8 с содержимым - java/lang/String.` — в ответе он писал про метаинформацию (в данном случае — про хранение имён классов в качестве строковых констант). Однако вопрос был про то, зачем вообще нужен `CONSTANT_Utf8` — а он нужен для хранения вообще любых строк. А чтобы не возникло следующего вопроса о том, зачем нужен другой, похожий тип `CONSTANT_String`, написал и про него.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, могу предположить, что вопрошающий искал ответ не в спецификации (которая легко ищется по запросу «java Utf8»), а в дизассемблировании метода, создающего пустой `String`.